# Open source bitcoin projects?

Tags: open-source, project

Is anyone involved in any open source projects? Anyone know of any? Maybe a nice list of different classes of projects would be good, I'd like to get my hands on some projects.

Comment: This is a bit to broad.  Most bitcoin related projects are open sourced.  It might help to narrow down what type of projects you are looking for (i.e. website payment processors, analytical tools, projects for a specific language, etc...)

Comment: I'm not quite sure, that is why I asked for a list so I could browse the different projects, are you involved in one yourself?

Comment: Well, I've researched a few of them, and I've contributed support by reviewing code and hunting bugs.  However, I'm not an active developer for any of them.  I've worked mostly with alt-coins.

Comment: For a quick-and-dirty approach, just google `bitcoin site:github.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of good resources to find these:

- https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:Open_Source
- <del>http://luke.dashjr.org/programs/bitcoin - bitgit</del>

Some of my favorites fall into the following categories:

## Address Generation

- [Brainwallet](https://github.com/brainwallet/brainwallet.github.com)
- [Vanitygen](https://github.com/samr7/vanitygen)

## Blockchain exploration

- [Bitcoin ABE](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe)

## Mining Pool software

- [Eloipool](https://gitorious.org/bitcoin/eloipool)

## Wallets

- [Armory](https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory)
- [Electrum](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum)